# Angular - difference between Model and Services

Tags: angular, typescript

I have take time to learn new technology and that technology is Angular(not JS)
So I have questions.

What is difference between Model and Services?
When we need use Model or Services?
I know that I can use DI for services and setup in provider and get singleton pattern.

Before, I wrote models only for business logic. For example: CURD operation to database, various validations and so on.

But I'm confuse between services and models, when I need use services and when I need use model. Could you someone show me in code and explain?

Many thanks!

Comment: There is no **need** to use a service. Services have some features that are handy in some situation - for example that they are instantiated and passed by DI. Besides that, both are just classes and you have to decide yourself what you want to use for what purpose.

Answer (score 10):

I usually treat it in the following way, but it all depends on how you look on the application and my answer might not fully fit your architectural decisions.

So let's begin with the **Model**:

Model is like *DTO*. Usually it just holds some data and provides some methods to work with that data. Models in my projects are not marked as `@Injectable()`, so I just `import` them on top and use them as needed.

Example:

```
export class Car {
   name: string;
   speed: number;

   constructor(name: string) {
      this.name = name;
      this.speed = 0;
   }

   accelerate(delta: number): void {
      this.speed += delta;
   }
}
```

**Services**:

Service is like *Layer* in your architecture. I use services to manipulate the data, e.g. perform GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests, map responses to actual **Models**, etc. All of them are marked as `@Injectable()` and shared between numerous modules in the app.

Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService {
    getAll(): Observable<Car[]> {
        // GET api/cars and map JSON response to the Car[] here
    }
}
```

To summarize: If something should manipulate data that belongs to it, it's more likely a **Model** and if it should manipulate different sets of data and share it across different modules it's more likely a **Service**

However couple years ago there was a practice when MVC used "Active" model and it was responsible for synchronizing own state with the backend, but anyway it usually had **Service** injected into it with the API calls logic encapsulated into that service.

UPD: Added some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Model is **basic Structure of an object**.
Like what are different properties of a **User Object**.It could have First name,Last name,Cars he owned etc.

> In angular you can define a basic **user** model as:

```
export class User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName:string
    carsOwned: [Cars];
    constructor() {     
        this.Cars = [new Cars()];  //create array instance of a Car
    }
}

export class Cars {
    name: string;
    brand: string;
    constructor() { 

    }
}
```

**2.** Services are like nervous system of your app that could add and fetch data from **a web service, local storage, a mock data source or share data within different classes**(by creating shared service).

> Below is an example of angular service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';


@Injectable()
export class SchoolsService {
  options: any;
  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  addUser(userObj) {

    return this.http.post(environment.baseURL + '/addUser',userObj, this.options).map(
      (response) => response.json()
    )

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take user authentification as an example.
A model is a representation of your Data. After an user types in his credentials, you could bundle the information in form of a `UserCredentials` model like this:

```
export class UserCredentials {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
```

You can use services for your business logic. This could be for example an authentification service which takes an `UserCredentials` model as an argument and processes the information:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthentificationService {
    authenticate(user: UserCredentials): boolean {
        // Your business logic here
    }
}
```

This approach is very useful to follow the SOLID Principles.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the use of the Observable pattern as a Controller in an MVC scaffolding and how that might be interpreted inside the Angular 2+ framework.

The Controller in an MVC scaffolding severed as the handler for data and events being passed back and forth between the View and the Model. In Angular the RxJs libraries Observable operate in that same function, having both a Subject and Listeners. In that context if you are using an Observable within your Service it's operating in this same space as a Controller, so in those situations I use Services. If however you are using an external class for data manipulation only I give it the class type of a Model.

Strictly speaking Angular is not an MVC, but as your application becomes larger it's a helpful organizational tool to break your code into their distinct responsibilities.